# Cannot delete message in IM channel as Slack bot

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm trying to use `chat.delete` on a "user" channel, the same as you do with `chat.postMessage`, however I keep getting a `channel_not_found` error.

```py
slack.api_call(
        "chat.delete",
        channel=userID, # Exact same value as used with chat.postMessage
        ts=ts
    )
```

Is this a limitation in their API? Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `chat.postMessage` will use the SlackBot channel when addressing a single user. The proper way of communicating via IM with a user is to use [conversations.open](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open). When I used that everything works as expected.

Comment: There is a "hack" which does not require conversations.open: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54930102/4379151