# How to send a message after adding a slack app to a workspace?

Tags: webhooks, slack, slack-api

I would like send a custom message to a channel, directly after a Slack app installation on the workspace.

I don't find a way to get "install" event installation.

So I thought to use bot user to send a message after the channel creation, but I found nothing about that neither...

Is there a trick to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "installation on this channel" ? You can only install a Slack app to a workspace, not to a channel. Unless you are talking about so called "workspace apps", which are deprecated.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken, sorry I misspoked. Yes I'm talking about installation on workspace, but I need to post the message on a specific channel.

Answer (score 1):

There is no installation event, but you don't need one. If you want to send a message after installation of you app to a workspace just add that function at the end of your installation script. e.g. right after you receive the new token for the workspace.

A popular approach is to send the "welcome message" in the app channel. Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753834/how-to-send-direct-messages-to-a-user-as-app-in-app-channel/47781750#47781750) about how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to figure this out myself within the Bolt framework. Here's how I've done it for the OAuth flow:

```py
def success(args: SuccessArgs) -> BoltResponse:
    assert args.request is not None

    team_client = WebClient(token=args.installation.bot_token)

    team_client.chat_postMessage(channel=args.installation.user_id, text="Welcome!")

    return args.default.success(args)


def failure(args: FailureArgs) -> BoltResponse:
    assert args.request is not None
    assert args.reason is not None

    return args.default.failure(args)


callback_options = CallbackOptions(success=success, failure=failure)

oauth_settings = OAuthSettings(
    # …
    callback_options=callback_options
)
```